# Cassandra installation / start on Windows 10 fails

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to get Cassandra 3.11.13 running on my Windows 10 machine.
There are reasons why I can't do in with docker and why I can't use the installer.

I am following these instructions:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-cassandra-on-windows

On a Windows command prompt, I launch the `cassandra.bat` batch file.

Any hints or tips what I am doing wrong?

```
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
    It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
    for performance and stability reasons.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "Start" mit 0 Argument(en):  "Falscher Parameter"
In D:\work\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:212 Zeichen:5


    $p.Start() | Out-Null
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception


Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "WaitForExit" mit 0 Argument(en):  "Diesem Objekt ist kein Prozess zugeordnet."
In D:\...\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:213 Zeichen:5

    $p.WaitForExit()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException


Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In D:\work\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:214 Zeichen:5

    $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull



Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In D:\...\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:218 Zeichen:9


    +     if ($stderr.Contains("Error"))
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull


Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In D:\...\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:231 Zeichen:5

    +     $sa = $stderr.Split("""")
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull


Es ist nicht möglich, einen Index auf ein NULL-Array anzuwenden.
In D:\...\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:232 Zeichen:5


    +     $env:JVM_VERSION = $sa[1]
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray


Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In D:\...\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:234 Zeichen:9

    if ($stderr.Contains("OpenJDK"))
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull



Es ist nicht möglich, einen Index auf ein NULL-Array anzuwenden.
In D:\work\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:247 Zeichen:5

$pa = $sa[1].Split("_")
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray



Es ist nicht möglich, einen Index auf ein NULL-Array anzuwenden.
In D:\..\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:248 Zeichen:5


    $subVersion = $pa[1]
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
    Performance of this node will suffer.
    Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*


Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In D:\...\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:406 Zeichen:9

    if ($env:JVM_VERSION.CompareTo("1.8.0") -eq -1 -or [convert]::ToI ...
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull



Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "Start" mit 0 Argument(en):  "Falscher Parameter"
In D:\...\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\bin\cassandra.ps1:251 Zeichen:9

    $p.Start() | Out-Null
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception


Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "WaitForExit" mit 0 Argument(en):  "Diesem Objekt ist kein Prozess zugeordnet."
In D:\..\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\bin\cassandra.ps1:253 Zeichen:9
    $p.WaitForExit()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

Answer (score 2):

The startup script is failing in multiple places because it is having issues parsing information about the Java JVM installed on the machine. Here is an example where it's failing:

```
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "Start" mit 0 Argument(en):  "Falscher Parameter"
In D:\work\tools\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:212 Zeichen:5
```

The most common causes of this issue are:

- Cassandra cannot find Java or Java is not installed
- incorrect version of Java is installed

Cassandra 3.11 only works with Java 8. It will not work with any newer versions of Java such as Java 11 or Java 17.

Make sure that you have installed Java 8 and that the environment variables for Java are configured correctly on your system.

I also wanted to let you know that there is very limited Windows support in Cassandra 3.11 and there are several known issues that will not be fixed due to limitations in the operating system.

Furthermore, Windows support has been completely dropped in Cassandra 4.0 due to lack of maintainers and testing ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

I realise you already mentioned that you can't/won't install on docker but I should mention that as a workaround, we recommend the following:

- [Deploy Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

If you just want to build apps with Cassandra as a backend, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) has a free tier that lets you launch a Cassandra cluster in a few clicks with no credit card required.

If none of these are appealing to you, I'm afraid that your options are limited. Cheers!